# arm asm: Value too large for field with numeric literal for :upper8_15:

Tags: assembly, gcc, arm, gnu-assembler, immediate-operand

GNU ARM assembler supports prefixes to extract group of bytes from a relocation value https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as.html#ARM_002dRelocations

On ARMv7m and later, the low/high 16 bit operators work fine, including with literal numbers not just symbol addresses.

```
    movw r0, #:lower16:0xabadcafe
    movt r0, #:upper16:0xabadcafe
```

But I cannot manage to get the 8 bits prefixes working with literals, on any arch (v6m, v7m, v8m):

```
       .thumb
       .text
test:
       movs    r0, #:upper8_15:0xabadcafe
```

Compiling this code returns an error; which is weird to me because the prefix is apparently ok with the parser (I was expecting a `bad expression` error), but instead is just doing nothing as the full 32 bits value is considered by the `movs` instruction.

```
$ ./arm-gnu-toolchain-12.2.rel1-x86_64-arm-none-eabi/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc -o test -mcpu=cortex-m23 -march=armv8-m.base -mthumb  -mpure-code -c test.S 

test.S: Assembler messages:
test.S:5: Error: invalid immediate: -1414673666 is out of range
test.S:5: Error: value of abadcafe too large for field of 2 bytes at 00000000
```

I made some research online and apparently this is supposed to work; the snippet in https://www.mail-archive.com/gcc-patches@gcc.gnu.org/msg230076.html is exactly what I want to achieve on v6m: loading a register without any data access using the prefix feature of the assembler.

Comment: If you supply a numerical constant, it appears that you'll have to supply a constant in the range `0x00--0xff`.  The relocation will not pick out the right bits.

Comment: Note also that you don't need these relocations for immediate values.  They only make sense for symbols and there they seem to work just fine.

Comment: @fuz `:upper16:` and `:lower16:` work fine with immediate values and not just relocations; why not the 8 bits version? Sounds like a fair use case to me..

Comment: There's no reason these should work with immediates.  I suspect that each relocation modifier (?) is hand coded and the code is not exactly the same.  Consider filing a bug against GNU binutils.

Comment: You do realize that for immediates, you can use arbitrary arithmetic expressions instead, right?  `movs r0, #((0xabadcafe >> 8) & 0xff)`.  They're probably assuming people would do it that way, and so didn't think it was important to support the reloc operators on immediates, or maybe just never thought to test them.

Comment: @NateEldredge it would be used from a macro. Why would they expect `:upper16:` to work on literals, but not `:upper0_7:`?

Comment: Immediates **can** be done with macros.  That would be the traditional approach.  For relocations, the linker must perform this.  The linker may not have the operations to support the byte selects.  The assembler must determine that it is a literal to be able to perform the byte select.  So, it is a more complex task to implement.  From the outside as a user, I would agree that it is perplexing, but the situation makes complete sense.  You can file a bug and see if  the developers agree and it gets fixed .  Certainly, a macro is a 'work around' or prospectively, the only supported feature.

Comment: @Benoit: I do agree that it is probably a bug that one works but not the other.  I'm just saying it's not a very surprising bug, since you're doing something that very few people would normally do.  Even in macros, I don't think most people necessarily expect to be able to use symbols and literals interchangeably as macro arguments.  It may even be that the assembler authors didn't particularly "expect" `:upper16:` to work on literals, but that it just happens to work due to the way it's implemented, whereas `:upper0_7:` is implemented in some other way that happens to not work.